# Poor performance from SQLite, big writes bring little reads to a crawl

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

**Related question**: [How to use SQLite in a multi-threaded application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680249/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-multi-threaded-application)

I've been trying to get decent performance out of SQLite3 in a multi-threaded program. I've been very impressed with its performance except for write latency. That's not it's fault, it has to wait for the disk to spin to commit the data. But having reads blocked during those writes, even if they could read from cache, is pretty intolerable.

My use case involves a large number of small read operations to get one tiny object by an indexed field, but latency is important for these operations because there are a lot of them. Writes are large and are accumulated into a single transaction. I don't want reads to have huge latency due to completing writes.

I first just used a single connection with a mutex to protect it. However, while the writing thread is waiting for the transaction to complete, readers are blocked on disk I/O because they can't acquire the mutex until the writer releases it. I tried using multiple connections, but then I get `SQLITE_LOCKED` from `sqlite3_step`, which means having to redesign all the reading code.

My write logic currently looks like this:

1. Acquire connection mutex.
2. `START TRANSACTION`
3. Do all writes. (Typically 10 to 100 small ones.)
4. `END TRANSACTION` -- here's where it blocks
5. Release mutex.

Is there some solution I'm not aware of? Is there an easy way to keep my readers from having to wait for the disk to finish rotating if the entry is in cache without having to rewrite all my reading code to handle `SQLITE_LOCKED`, reset, and retry?

Comment: `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF` will improve your write performance drastically at the expense of data corruption if something goes wrong before the data can be written. I use this in a project currently where this is not such an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is important and expected to survive process crashes, power losses, and so on. It is replicated, but each node is supposed to treat it as precious. It seems so senseless to delay reads, potentially from cache, while we wait for the write synch to be completed by the OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow multiple readers and one writer to access the database concurrently, enable [write-ahead logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

WAL works well with small transactions, so you don't need to accumulate writes.

Please note that WAL does not work with networked file systems, and for optimal performance, requires regular checkpointing.

Comment: That improved things by about a factor of 20, just by turning it on. Damn.

Comment: @Arash Because it has some restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sqlite offers multi-threaded support on it's own. You do not have to use your own mutexes, since you only slow the entire program down. Consult [sqlite thread options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe) if you have any doubts.

Using write-ahead log may solve your problems, but it is a double-edged sword. As long as there is a read ongoing, the inserted data will not be written to the main database file and the WAL journal will grow. This is covered in detail in [Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

I am using sqlite in WAL mode in one of my applications. For small amounts of data it works well. However, when there is a lot of data (several hundred inserts per second, in peaks even more) I experience some issues which I don't seem to be able to fix through any meddling with sqlite configuration.

What you may consider is using several database files, each assigned to a certain time span. This will be applicable only when your queries depend on time.

I am probably running too much ahead. WAL journal should help:)

Comment: I can't find a way to avoid my own mutexes. If I don't use them, I get `SQLITE_LOCKED` returns and have to implement retries. (Which might be worth doing. Before implementing WAL, my gut told me the code had about 100 times the latency it should. With WAL, my gut tells me it's about 5 times what it should be.)

Comment: I don't know the detals of your application and how it works. If you need to use your own mutexes and it makes the code run better - so be it. In such case you may, under certain coditions, disable sqlite mutexes alltogether. In the case you showed mutex usage will significantly slow down read operations, because only one read at a time will be possible. Using sqlite internal mutexes multiple reads may be possible.

Comment: Is there a way to get multiple reads, single writer with SQLite doing the mutexes without having to implement `SQLITE_LOCKED` retries?

Comment: It is a known problem of [readers-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). There are some implementation but usually there is a risk of reader/writer starvation.