# SQLite multiprocess access

Tags: database, sqlite

I think it is very simple question. But I can't resolve it myself.
I have two applications. 
One writes to sqlite3 databse at the very rapid pace - about 6 transaction blocks per second.
The another one is supposed to read data from database sometimes.
How should I design this two applications? For now when 1st application is writing another one fails with error "database is locked" at either funcs I have tried to execute: SQLite3_Open or SQLite3_Open_v2 with SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY flag.
**THE MAIN QUESTION IS**:Is one appliocation able to do 'SELECT' while another is spaming 'INSERT' **at all**?
If no what should I do? 
 
Close writing database connection, then open another database connection, do select, then close it, then open writing connection back again and continue inserting? In another words **do I have to** "invent" some mechanism which would control separte database access from these "read" and "write" applications?
If yes, than is there possibility for apllcation "A" to force close applcation's "B" connection 
Thank you!

Comment: This link may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680249/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-multi-threaded-application

Answer (score 2):

SQLite can handle multiple processes fine.  With WAL support you can even read from the database from one connection while another is writing.  Six transactions per second is not many at all, assuming each doesn't take more than 166ms each.

Locking is usually returned when you step through a statement, not when you open a database.  Is it possible the first connection was opened with `SQLITE_OPEN_EXCLUSIVE`?  That would cause another process to be unable to open the connection.  If that's the case, remove that flag.