# multithread database is locked Sqlite windows phone 8.1 RT

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

I can't Access database with multithread. It's Exception database is locked or database is busy. I dont understand why database is locked when I read or write in different table.
I try code below to multithread

```
SQLite3.Config(SQLite3.ConfigOption.MultiThread);
```

It's not working. Anyone know? I need it so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multi threaded application, then both thread have the liberty to update the DB. But inside DB, The first update will take lock on the rows you are trying to update, and if the second update also tries to work on the locked rows, then you have the possibility of getting "locked" or "busy", if the first update request take more the x amount of time, where "x" is configurable.

Comment: It will be interesting to check the behavior by using global mutex when you try to update, insert on the tables. Reads must not use mutex.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SQLite web site](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html):

> SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time. For many situations, this is not a problem. Writer queue up. Each application does its database work quickly and moves on, and no lock lasts for more than a few dozen milliseconds. But there are some applications that require more concurrency, and those applications may need to seek a different solution.

So, you could use SQL from different threads for reading, but not for writing *concurrently*. There are many answers for this in stackoverflow. See for instance: [How to use SQLite in a multi-threaded application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680249/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-multi-threaded-application)

Comment: I think SQlite can't write simultaneous. So, if i can use DBMS. Does it can multithread write simultaneous ?

Comment: You can have different threads, and in each thread you can read and/or write to the database. But you cannot, in two different threads, write *simultaneously* to the database, given the limitations of SQLite. It is not a “real” DBMS, since it does not manage directly the concurrency, but uses the Operating System primitives to lock the file containing the database.