# Slow Sqlite3 Select Query while Insert/Update/Delete has no issue

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite

I am stuck in a issue related to slow sqlite3 select. I have searched alot on this forum and have applied many of the suggestion which has somewhere helped me in moving ahead. I assume there are some fault in the way i am trying to use sqlite or may be the settings which i have used while compiling it.

I decided to use sqlite3 in c++ after reading a lot about its performance. Since the data inflow is very high and the server is set in co-location at exchange , if the packet processing is delayed due to any reason there canbe a packet drop and a delayed packet is of no use in High Frequency
trading environment. There can be a minimum packet flow of 5 mbps where each packet is of a maximum 45 bytes size. My sqlite is set for In Memory 
use.

To understand my comlete issue please go through the details below.

Below are the details of the Server:

Server Details on which i am trying to use Sqlite3

- Architecture:          x86_64
- CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
- Byte Order:            Little Endian
- CPU(s):                16
- On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
- Thread(s) per core:    2
- Core(s) per socket:    4
- Socket(s):             2
- NUMA node(s):          2
- Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
- CPU family:            6
- Model:                 45
- Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2643 0 @ 3.30GHz
- Stepping:              7
- CPU MHz:               3400.160
- BogoMIPS:              6603.86
- Virtualization:        VT-x
- L1d cache:             32K
- L1i cache:             32K
- L2 cache:              256K
- L3 cache:              10240K
- NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14
- NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15
- Ram: 48 gb
- Operating System : CentOS 7
- Kernel Version     : Linux version 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) )

Details of process which i am using:

Compiling Sqlite3 with the following command

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static CFLAGS="-O3 -m64 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS=0 -DSQLITE_CONFIG_SINGLETHREAD -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_AUTOMATIC_INDEX=0 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=4096 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=4000 -DHAVE_FDATASYNC=0"
```

Create Table Query :

```
create table 'Stream0' ( TokenNo int NOT NULL,OrderId integer NOT NULL,SIDE int NOT NULL,PRICE int NOT NULL,QTY int NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (OrderId));
```

Index On Table :

```
CREATE INDEX DataFilterIndex ON 'Stream0'(TokenNo , SIDE, Price,Qty);
```

Pragma Statement :

```
void SqliteManager::SetPragma()
{
   rc= sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
   rc= sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA count_changes = false", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
   rc= sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF", NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
}
```

Preparing Sqlite Query :

```
MyString <<"insert or replace into 'Stream0' values( ?1,?2,?3,?4,?5);";
rc= sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,MyString.str().c_str(),strlen(MyString.str().c_str()),&insert_stmt,NULL);
```

Note : -- Insert or replace has been used because the incoming data for any specified TokenNo may be with modify tag without any insert tag               prior to this.

```
MyString.str(std::string());
MyString <<"delete from 'Stream0' where OrderId = ?1;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,MyString.str().c_str(),strlen(MyString.str().c_str()),&delete_stmt,NULL);
```

Once either data for specific TokenNo is asked to delete/Insert/Modify a select statement is raised to publish data to the user.

Select Statement:

```
MyString<<"select TokenNo,Price ,sum(QTY) from 'Stream0' where TokenNo=?1 and Side=66 group by Price order by Price desc limit 5";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,MyString.str().c_str(),strlen(MyString.str().c_str()),&select_bid_stmt,NULL);
```

Here Side = 66 stands for price of Buyers and Price desc says price sorted in decreasing order.

One more is there which has Side = 83 which stands for Sellers and Price Asc says price sorted in ascending mode

If Insert/Modify data comes for a token then one of the query is raised either with Side = 66 or Side = 83 depending on the Side received in the incoming data Packet.

If Delete packet is recieved then Both of the query has to be released back to back.

If I run my executable with Insert/Replace/delete every thing goes well i.e : No packet drop, but the moment I start using Select query     either single after Insert/Replace or both after Delete, packet drop starts.

I hope I have been able to describe my whole situation. Running Select query is a must for me. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are polling heavily listening for incoming packets but you query routine is just not fast enough. 
   You are using a powerful Xeon E5 processor capable of doing heavy duty muti-threading but you have configured the sqlite3 in single threaded mode. Try opening the database in multi- threading mode. Better keep the packet listener in one thread so that the main GUI thread remains responsive.Worker threads can easily perform the insert/delete/query database routines.

Comment: Sorry , one mistake on my part. There are total of 5 separate streams. Each of them running on separate thread. The one I mentioned above is of first stream.  As much I am getting your suggestion : should I run insert/update/delete on one thread and select on another?

Comment: Separate threads as listeners,that's OK. If you use sqlite3 in MT mode you can allow worker threads to handle each of insert/update/query all separately, that way you don't loose incoming data. For this open the database in MT mode in each methods otherwise it will  get blocked as in your case.

Comment: I went through your suggestion and then studied more on MT in sqlite3 where i found a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680249/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-multi-threaded-application)  which says "SQLite has a very conservative threading model, when you do a write operation" and one more [link](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) from sqlite page says "Multi-thread : In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads."

Comment: So I am a bit confused that if one connection can't be used by multiple thread then how will i be able to call select statement from different thread.Now my compile time statement is 

./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static CFLAGS="-O3 -m64 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS=0 -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_AUTOMATIC_INDEX=0 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE=4096 -DSQLITE_DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE=4000 -DHAVE_FDATASYNC=0"

Is it possible for you to guide me with a sample?

Comment: See you have 5 streams for which you have 5 listener threads. These threads will insert data to your tables. To further speed up your processing , you can allow addl worker threads to do the insert , update, query. But to ensure that these new addl worker threads
work in unison concurrently, you have to ensure that no single database connection is used  simultaneously in other threads. This can be achieve by opening a new instance of the table and not sharing other instances.

void Insert(Data data,table_t table)
{
   //open table in MT mode

   //close table

}