# If there is a potential for multiple threads to do an insert / update into a SQLite database, should I always use lock?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I have this code that uses lock:

```
            lock (l)
            {
                db2.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    rc1 = db2.Execute(s);
                    db2.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    db2.Rollback();
                    Crashes.TrackError(ex,
                        new Dictionary<string, string> {
                            {"RunExecute", "Exception"},
                            {"sql", s },
                            {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
                        });
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

and other code that doesn't:

```
            db2.Insert(new QuizHistory()
            {
                QuizId = quiz,
                Cards  = (App.viewablePhrases ?? GetViewablePhrases(MO.Quiz)).Count,
                Score = score,
                UtcNow = (int)Math.Truncate(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds),
                Viewed = 1,
                Deck   = Helpers.Deck.GetTitle()
            });
```

To reduce the chance of issues, should I be adding lock(l) around all the code that accesses the database?

Comment: Yes you should.

Answer (score 0):

**You must provide access to SQLite database only one thread at one time.**

SQLite is a file-based database so accessing multiple threads to file (using one `SQLiteConnection`) causing unpredictable behaviour and corruption errors.

If you use [SQLite-Net-PCL](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library for manipulation SQLite database then you should look at [asynchronous API](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/Asynchronous-API) for multiple threads concurrent access to SQLite database.

Fore more information about SQLite database multithreading support please refer [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) and [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680249/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-multi-threaded-application)